# Apple silicon failed to start project Nuxtjs project

Tags: nuxt.js, apple-m1

I install homebrew native on my m1 MacBook Pro, and I installed yarn and node using home-brew without any problem but after I try to start my project it raises error say
`error Command failed with signal "SIGILL"`

Comment: I could be wrong, bug this is probably better as a bug report than a question. It will probably take a bit before everything is stable on arm mac.

Comment: I just bought a MacbookPro which includes M1 apple and I am facing slow performance when starting a nuxt project. It takes around 1h to launch the app...I suppose Nuxt people need to check that as well...